# Set playback speed on CastSDK v3

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast

I am developing a chromecast app along with exoplayer.

In exoplayer I can simply:

```
player.setPlaybackParameters(new PlaybackParameters(speed));
```

Where speed is any float like 0.5, 2.0, etc.

Now I must implement this same logic in Chromecast using the CastSDK v3.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use LoadRequestData: https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/caf_receiver/cast.framework.messages.LoadRequestData

Use that with the PlayerManager: https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/caf_receiver/cast.framework.PlayerManager#load

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get how to pass the speed yet. Should use customData? I must change it while the video is reproducing too. Does this works with a styled media receiver or only with custom receivers with the proper logic implemented?